# Matlab motion detection using IP Webcam giving weird colors

Tags: android, matlab, video-processing, matlab-cvst, motion-detection

This code uses an android phone and the app "IP Webcam" (the url is provided by the app) and the phone and laptop are connected via the phone's hotspot. I'm having a little bit of problem with the video colors. They are only shades of yello/white and black. Can someone please help me out with getting a proper video ? or atleast a better one than this? code: http://pastebin.com/RPBCVrzu
I pasted it here as well for convinience:

```
% vidDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_640x480', ...
% 'ROI', [1 1 640 480], ...
% 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'rgb');
url = 'http://192.168.43.1:8080/shot.jpg';
ss  = imread(url);
optical = vision.OpticalFlow('OutputValue', 'Horizontal and vertical components in complex form');
% maxWidth = imaqhwinfo(vidDevice,'MaxWidth');
% maxHeight = imaqhwinfo(vidDevice,'MaxHeight');
maxWidth=size(ss,2);
maxHeight=size(ss,1);
shapes = vision.ShapeInserter;
shapes.Shape = 'Lines';
shapes.BorderColor = 'Custom';
shapes.CustomBorderColor = [255 0 0];
r = 1:5:maxHeight;
c = 1:5:maxWidth;
[Y, X] = meshgrid(c,r);
 hVideoIn = vision.VideoPlayer;
 hVideoIn.Name = 'Original Video';
hVideoIn.Position = [30 100 640 480];
hVideoOut = vision.VideoPlayer;
hVideoOut.Name = 'Motion Detected Video';
hVideoOut.Position = [700 100 640 480];
nFrames = 0;
while (nFrames < Inf)
%rgbData = step(vidDevice);
rgbData=single(imread(url));
optFlow = step(optical,rgb2gray(rgbData));
optFlow_DS = optFlow(r, c);
H = imag(optFlow_DS)*50;
V = real(optFlow_DS)*50;
lines = [Y(:)'; X(:)'; Y(:)'+V(:)'; X(:)'+H(:)'];
rgb_Out = step(shapes, rgbData, lines');
step(hVideoIn, rgbData);
step(hVideoOut, rgb_Out);
nFrames = nFrames + 1;
end
release(hVideoOut);
release(hVideoIn);
release(vidDevice);
```

Comment: Why are some lines commented out? Are those the parts you used when the camera was directly connected? Because if that's for the same camera, it might be a colorspace issue.

Comment: Yes.That was for getting the video from the webcam of the laptop. Can you help me correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

`'YUY2_640x480'` indicates that the video is coming in in YUV format, rather than RGB.  There are two ways to fix that.  If you type `imaqtool`, you should see a list of all camera formats visible to MATLAB. If you see something like `RGB_640x480`, that should give you RGB video.  If not, then try converting the frame you are currently getting to RGB using `ycbcr2rgb` function.

Comment: But I'm not using that line of code. That has been commented out as it was for the integrated laptop webcam. I need a solution for the weird colors from the phone's cam :/